# Radio button filter legend in Custom Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, checkbox, google-maps-api-3, filter, google-maps-markers

I am new to Google Maps Api. I have done a lot so far and really like working with this. But there is one issue I would like your help with since I can't figure it out and it would save me a lot of time. How can I add a simple filter in my legend? Just a simple dropdown box that hides/shows markers. Would really appreciate any help I can get with this! This is my map now (with a lot more markers normally):

```
<head>
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 420px;margin:10px 0px 30px;">
  <div class="container">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 9,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.524500, -4.882175),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker1 = new google.maps.LatLng(36.521604, -5.046373);
    var marker2 = new google.maps.LatLng(36.558387, -4.929676);
    var marker3 = new google.maps.LatLng(36.503746, -4.843931);


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: marker1,
        url: 'marker1.html',
        title: 'marker1',
        icon: 'marker1.png',
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: marker2,
        url: 'marker2.html',
        title: 'marker2',
        icon: 'images/markers/marker2.png',
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: marker3,
        url: 'marker3',
        title: 'marker3',
        icon: 'images/markers/marker3.png',
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.open(this.url, '_blank');
    });


  </script>

</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Google provides an example of how to hide markers here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to have more options (drop down) where you can select if all the 'marker1' markers als shown or all the 'marker3' markers etc. So unfortunately this doesn't work for me.